# Getting program to run on command

Tags: c, linux

I'm new here so sorry if this is a dumb/bad question but I just cannot figure out how to do it for the life of me.

So how would one go about linking a c program to a command. For example lets say I had **helloworld.c** and I entered **make helloword** and then wanted to run the command **helloworld** to run helloworld anywhere on the system. How would I go about this (not using bash aliases).

Comment: This is more a question  on the linux environment.  There are paths (set up for the current user, and all the users on the system.  These are searched for a name ('helloworld') if `helloworld` is placed in a directory which is searched, it will be available to everybody.  If these are amended to include a new directory, then helloworld can be added there.

Answer (score 0):

Compiles the program and link it as an executable to `a.out`

```
gcc helloworld.c
```

Execute the file

```
./a.out
```

Comment: It's not a solution to OP as It says "how would one go about linking a c program to a command"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `helloworld` executable is in `newDir` directory in the `home` folder.

Then the absolute path for *`helloworld`* is `/home/user_name/newDir/helloworld`

Now add the below line your `~/.bashrc` file.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user_name/newDir/
```

Now open any new terminal (any directory), you will be able to run the command `helloworld`

Adding the path of the executable in the [`PATH` environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) will allow the user to run the executable available in the mentioned directory any where in the system. Check the value of your `$PATH` with `echo $PATH`. It probably contains the system directories `/usr/bin` and `/bin` where most system executables sit. But don't mess these directories by adding your own programs there (leave them to be handled by your [package manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager)).

You might want to avoid having a too long `PATH` environment variable; then, assuming you do have a `$HOME/bin/` directory mentioned in that `$PATH`, you could just add a symbolic link there, e.g.

```
ln -sv /home/user_name/newDir/helloworld $HOME/bin/helloworld
```

Answer (score -1):

Well you would be running it using the ./(outputfilename)
So to assign a name we use the comment gcc -o desiredOPname  filename.c
And then run it as ./desiredOPname